# SharePoint 2013 Datepicker Not Rendering Correctly

Tags: 2013, css, custom, datepicker

I’m having a problem with my Calendar datepicker in Sharepoint 2013. It’s like it is missing some CSS.

[image]

And I get the below error in my console :

> Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type
>   text/html:
>   "http://hub-pilot.com/programs/ftmba/2016/_layouts/15/defaultcss.ashx?ctag=21".
>   iframe.aspx?&cal=1&lcid=1033&langid=1033&tz=-08:00:00.0003650&ww=0111110&fdow=0&fwoy=0&hj=0&swn=Fal…:5

A solution I have tried, but did not work is as follows:

- **Placing Master Page in same folder of masterpage**

I have all my styles/layouts/css/js in a separate folder in the masterpage folder. I have this working on one site collection, but for some reason it is not working on this separate one.

Any thoughts?

Comment: helped my solution to you?

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a root(/) site collection in the web application and see if it fixes the problem. I have seen this issue with SharePoint 2010 under certain situations.

Comment: I've seen this as well when certain Javascript and CSS files don't download correctly.  Have a look at the resources being called and loaded when the page opens.  If that is the case you may have a bad cache somewhere (SP servers, or Load balancer) that you will need to clear.

Answer (score 0):

It looks you created your own master page. Use GhostableInLibrary type in `Elements.xml` and reactivate feature which includes this master page.

```
File Path="My.master" Url="My.master" Type="GhostableInLibrary" ReplaceContent="TRUE"
```